# github's recommended maximum file size

Tags: git, github

I have tried to do a commit with git command line tool, I've runned following sequence of commands:

```
git add -A  
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

But I've got an error because some files exceed a certain size:

[image]

So I've deleted that file and launched again:

```
git add -A  
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

But again getting same error!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the file in a separate commit is not good enough. The file will still be in git's history. You need to amend the original commit that added the file so that the file never gets added in the first place.

```
git checkout <problematic commit hash>
git rm filename foobar.exe
git commit --amend
git push
```

---

#### Git Large File Storage

Github is rolling out support for [Large File Storage](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs). You might be able to use that to store a file larger than 100M, if you really need to. But you should also consider if putting a JDK in version control is really necessary.